# How to log custom data in Flask-MonitoringDashboard?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am monitoring my API using `flask_monitoringdashboard`. API can be accessed here `http://localhost:5000/price/https://example.com`.
I want to somehow log that `https://example.com` part for all requests and show it on dashboard.

```
from flask import Flask, Response
import flask_monitoringdashboard as dashboard

app = Flask(__name__)
dashboard.config.init_from(file='/dashboardconfig/config.cfg')
dashboard.bind(app)

@app.route('/price/<path:url>/')
def FetchPrice(url):
    if "xyz.com" in url:
        return Response("200.5$",status=200)
    else:
        return Response("Bad Request", status=400)
```

Here is `config.cfg`

```
[dashboard]
APP_VERSION=1.0
CUSTOM_LINK=dashboard
MONITOR_LEVEL=3
OUTLIER_DETECTION_CONSTANT=2.
[authentication]
USERNAME=admin
PASSWORD=admin
SECURITY_TOKEN=XXXXxxxXXXxxXXxXXxXX
[database]
DATABASE=sqlite:///flask_monitoringdashboard.db
[visualization]
TIMEZONE=America/Bogota
COLORS={'main':'[0,97,255]', 'static':'[255,153,0]'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the answer here in case it's useful for somebody else, for sure the OP is not interested in the answer anymore two years later:

You can't do what you want with the current version of the `flask_monitoringdashboard`.